WebView Navigated Event Not Triggered in .NET MAUI
I am experiencing an issue with the WebView control in my .NET MAUI app where the Navigated event does not fire after navigation.
Here’s the scenario:

The Source property of the WebView is set to a valid URL.
I have subscribed to the Navigated event both in XAML and C#.
Despite this, the Navigated event handler is not invoked after the navigation is completed.
4.Navigating event is getting triggered as expected

I am implementing an activity indicator while the web view is loading the page. The activity indicator is made visible when Navigating event is triggered but never goes off even after page is loaded because Navigated event is not getting triggered.
Environment:
.NET MAUI Project targeting Android, iOS, and Windows
Android 34.0, iOS, and Windows 10.0.19041.0 platform versions
Troubleshooting Done:
Verified that the Navigated event is subscribed properly.
Ensured the URL is valid and accessible via a regular browser.
Confirmed platform-specific configurations:
Android: INTERNET permission is present in AndroidManifest.xml.
Why is the Navigated event not being triggered, and how can I resolve this issue? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

you are using custom webviewhandler for you webview?

I can see code like the below
/// Class implements the Android specific configuration for the .NET MAUI web view.
internal partial class WebViewConfigurationService {
/// Class implements a custom web view client for the Android web view.
private class AndroidWebViewClient(WebViewConfigurationService service) : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient {
/// Attribute stores the configuration service in which the client is used.
private readonly WebViewConfigurationService service = service;
Does this mean there is a custom webviewhandler for the webview?

please provide how you defined your webview in xaml if there is a custom handler defined , then it's should be configured in app start, more likely in mauiprogram.cs

Its a simple configuration in xaml with WebView tag and few properties defined. No handlers are registered in mauiprogram.cs. But the Android.Webkit.WebViewClient class is used in Android to manage various behaviors of a WebView.
The WebView is contained in a WebViewPage. In WebViewPage has an object of WebViewConfigurationService.
internal partial class WebViewConfigurationService {
/// Class implements a custom web view client for the Android web view.
private class AndroidWebViewClient(WebViewConfigurationService service) : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient {

can you remove this extra implementation and check whether Navigated event is firing?

"Navigated" works if the extra implementation is removed. The extra implementation is when the webView.HandlerChanged is triggered the platform view web client is set to AndroidWebViewClient as below -
if (webView.Handler?.PlatformView is not Android.Webkit.WebView platformView) {
return false;
}
platformView.SetWebViewClient(new AndroidWebViewClient(this));

check my answer, give it a try.

When you set a custom AndroidWebViewClient using
platformView.SetWebViewClient(new AndroidWebViewClient(this));

it replaces the default WebView client, which is responsible for triggering the Navigated event.
You can modify your AndroidWebViewClient to explicitly trigger the Navigated event in the onPageFinished method.
private class AndroidWebViewClient : Android.Webkit.WebViewClient
{
    private readonly WebViewConfigurationService service;
    private readonly WebView webView;

    public AndroidWebViewClient(WebViewConfigurationService service, WebView webView)
    {
        this.service = service;
        this.webView = webView;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        var navigatedEventArgs = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(
        WebNavigationEvent.NewPage,
        url,
        null,
        WebNavigationResult.Success
        );
        // Manually invoke the Navigated event
        if (webView != null)
        {
            var navigatedEvent = webView.GetType().GetField(
            nameof(WebView.Navigated),
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | 
            System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

           if (navigatedEvent != null)
           {
              var eventDelegate = 
              (MulticastDelegate)navigatedEvent.GetValue(webView);
             if (eventDelegate != null)
             {
                foreach (var handler in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
                 {
                    handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[] { webView, navigatedEventArgs });
                 }
             }
        }
    }
}

And while setting webview client pass the Maui WebView
if (webView.Handler?.PlatformView is Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
{
    platformView.SetWebViewClient(new AndroidWebViewClient(this, webView));
}


webView.Handler?.Invoke(nameof(WebView.Navigated), navigatedEventArgs); did not work. OnPageFinished is invoked after the page is loaded but the actual Navigated event of the WebView is not invoked.
I tried reflection approach(pls check next comment) to invoke Navigated and it worked. But I believe there should be a simpler approach without reflection. Please let mw know if you are aware.

var navigatedEvent = webView.GetType().GetField(nameof(WebView.Navigated), System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (navigatedEvent != null)
{
var eventDelegate = (MulticastDelegate)navigatedEvent.GetValue(webView);
if (eventDelegate != null)
{
foreach (var handler in eventDelegate.GetInvocationList())
{
handler.Method.Invoke(handler.Target, new object[] { webView, navigatedEventArgs });
}
}
}

Updated answer with your approach... i will let you know if i find anything simpler
